# Writing information from a LKM to userspace using the proc file system

Tags: c, linux, struct, linux-kernel

I'm trying to write data to user space from a linux kernel module function using the `proc` filesystem.  I'd like to use the `seq_file` iteration implementation so it handles the page size and all that good stuff.  I have a function that is constantly logging data and creating a struct and populating the struct with the data.  I would like to pump these structs to the `proc` file system so the application in the user space can grab these structs and appropriately process them.  When the user space is ready to receive the data it will read from the proc file system which will kick all this off.  I'm thinking I can't pass the struct into the `seq_file show` function.  So can I declare the struct globally and print it to the `/proc/info` file from the `seq_show` function?  Below I'm currently trying to implement.

```
  typedef struct data_t{
    unint32_t address;
    unint8_t pid;
    unint8_t info;
  } data_t;

  data_t data = NULL;

  static void datalog(uint32_t addy, unint8_t info){
   // this function is constantly logging data
   data->address = addy;
   data->info = info;
  }

  static void *seq_start(struct seq_file *s, loff_t *pos)
  {
     // seq file start stuff
  }

  static int seq_show(struct seq_file *s, void *v)
  {
   //print the data struct to the /proc/info file
   return 0;
   }

   static void *seq_next(struct seq_file *s, void *v, loff_t *pos)
   {
   // move the pointer along
   return v;
   }

   static void seq_stop(struct seq_file *s, void *v)
   {

   }

  static struct seq_operations seq_ops = {
 .start = seq_start,
 .next  = seq_next,
 .stop  = seq_stop,
 .show  = seq_show
  };

static int open(struct inode *inode, struct file *file)
{
 return seq_open(file, &seq_ops);
};

static struct file_operations fops = {
 .owner   = THIS_MODULE,
 .open    = open,
 .read    = seq_read,
 .llseek  = seq_lseek,
 .release = seq_release
};

 static int init(void)
 {
 struct proc_dir_entry *entry = NULL;
 entry = proc_create("info", 0777, NULL, &fops);
 data = (data_t *) kmalloc(sizeof(data_t), GFP_KERNEL);
 return 0;
 }
```

So the `datalog` function is already in a constant loop.  I'd like to pump all those structs to the `/proc/info` file so they can be appropriately processed in user space.  This is going to be rapid fire data so it doesn't feel like `copy_to_user` is the way to go.  As you can see I'm not sure what I'm doing so any direction or help is greatly appreciated!  Thanks!

Comment: `procfs` is intended to be used for seldom-accessed text data. Why are you using it?

Comment: CL my friend, I'd like to use it to get logging info from kernel space to a user space application.  Thanks!

Comment: More information about the logging would be helpful. Where are you logging ? Are you maintaining a log buffer containing data_t structs ? Also, do you want all the log information when you read the proc file or only the unread info ?

Comment: Thanks for the help!  I'm logging info about a specific process so EIP, registers,  etc. So as you can imagine it's rapidly changing and I'd like to dump this info to the proc file system so my user space application can process it.  And I'd like only the unread info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are maintaining an array of `struct data` and count is the no of such structures. The below functions should help you to read the structures from userspace. The below code assumes that the log buffer or the array is not modified when you are reading it (It's a simple example). You can modify the below to suit your needs. Make sure to synchronize your data structures such as the log buffer to make sure what you read is what is present.

And Yes! you can use globally declare the structure and use it within seq_show.

```
static void *seq_start(struct seq_file *s, loff_t *pos)
{
    if (*pos > count)
        return NULL;
    return pos;
}

static int seq_show(struct seq_file *s, void *v)
{
    loff_t *pos = (loff_t *)v;

    if (*pos == 0) {
        seq_printk(s, "Address\t\t\tPID\tInfo\n");
    }
    seq_printk(s, "0x%p\t%u\t%u\n", drv_data[*pos].address, drv_data[*pos].pid,
                     drv_data[*pos].info);
    return 0;
}

static void *seq_next(struct seq_file *s, void *v, loff_t *pos)
{
    (*pos)++;
    if (*pos >= count)
        return NULL;
    return pos;
}
```